Error : the URL returned from login must be set in sforceservice
I am a new SFDC sysadmin. I am trying to import data into sandbox environment using data loader and I am seeing the error "the URL returned from login must be set in sforceservice" when trying to connect/login to the sandbox environment using data loader.
I tried to follow below link for the solution but it didn't help.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386598&type=1
I need some help resolving this.
TIA

Have you seen this related article? There's a setting that you can set which should fix the problem.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386667&type=1  - This article helped with the error
